# Edit raster based on attribute of sf polygons

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I've been puzzling over this for days.  I have a raster I need to edit based on polygon attributes in an sf object.  The two objects have the same extent.

## Raster filled with 9's

```
r <- raster( nrow=10, ncol=10, xmn=0, xmx=10, ymn=0, ymx=10 )
values(r) <- 9

> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 9, 9  (min, max)
```

## Two triangles with attributes 1 and NA.

```
# Make two triangles (sfg objects)
p1 <- matrix( c(0,0, 10,0, 0,10, 0,0), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
p1 <- st_polygon(list( p1 ) )
p2 <- matrix( c(10,0, 10,10, 0,10, 10,0), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
p2 <- st_polygon(list( p2 ) )

#Combine into a simple feature geometry column
p.sfc <- st_as_sfc( list( p1, p2 ))

# Make data frame with 1 attribute
df <- data.frame( attr=c(1,NA))

# Combine df and geometry column into sf object
p.sf <- st_sf( df, p.sfc )
# Set same CRS (has no effect on results)
p.sf <- st_set_crs( x=p.sf, value=4326 )

> p.sf
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
  attr                          p.sfc
1    1 POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 0 10, ...
2   NA POLYGON ((10 0, 10 10, 0 10...
```

[image]

Here's what I've tried to put NA where the NA polygon is.  `raster::mask` should "Create a new Raster* object that has the same values as x, except for the cells that are NA (or other maskvalue) in a 'mask'. These cells become NA (or other updatevalue)."  Neither gives an error and neither changes the raster.

```
rm <- mask( x=r, mask=p.sf )
rm <- mask( x=r, mask=as_Spatial( p.sf ) )
```

Edit: Also not working:

## Edit 2: actually, this works.

When experimenting I failed to examine the raster closely enough to see the NA values.  However, it seems to work oppositely from the documentation.  It is keeping the raster cells that are under NA polygon and changing everything else to NA.  I'm still confused.

```
rm <- mask( x=r, mask=p.sf[ is.na(p.sf$attr), ] )
```

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my answer, it is giving an unexpected result and maintaining the raster cells' values whose center is covered by a spatial polygon feature, regardless of the feature's value.  So, you are now selecting the polygon feature that has NA value; that is why it is preserving those raster values.  But this is not what you wanted, so given the function's unexpected behavior, my answer gives the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree this is an unexpected result based on `mask` documentation.

It appears the raster cells will be converted to `NA` if the center of the cell is not covered by a spatial polygon.  So, one of your possible solutions was close `rm <- mask( x=r, mask=p.sf[p.sf$attr==1, ] )`, but failed, because this logical indexing  `c(TRUE,NA)` was trying to return an object where the second feature had an empty geometry.  Here is a correct way to do the indexing.

```
rm <- mask(x=r, mask=p.sf[!is.na(p.sf$attr),])
rm
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 9, 9  (min, max)
plot(rm)

#or your idea would have worked with which, because it removes NA values
mask( x=r, mask=p.sf[which(p.sf$attr==1), ] )
```

[image]

Interestingly, if the polygon features are converted to a raster via `rasterize`, then `mask` also gives the desired output via an expected result

```
rNA <- r
values(rNA) <- NA
rs <- rasterize(p.sf, rNA, field='attr', update=TRUE)
plot(rs)
```

[image]

```
mask_result <- mask(x=r, mask=rs)
plot(mask_result)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I added that second edit before I saw your answer.  I will be able to make this work for my real application.  Thank you.

Comment: No worries.  Glad it will work.  BTW, nice reproducible example!

Comment: Have also added another solution using rasterize first on the polgyons, which does give the expected result when using mask

Answer (score 1):

In my real data, this worked, but it took 6-8 hours (~13 million raster cells and 300,000 polygons).  Since the part of the raster that needs replacing with NAs is a small part, I thought it might be more efficient to select those corresponding polygons rather than the rest.  @ThetaFC's answer revealed the possibility of using `rasterize` for this without `mask`.

The `rasterize` documentation is even more confusing to me than `mask`, so with tons of trial and error, I finally found this (using the example data above).  With my real data, this takes only about 40 minutes.

```
# Subset polys to the part that needs editing in raster
p <- subset( p.sf, is.na( attr ) )

# 'field' in this case is the replacement value 
# (can't seem to replace directly with NA)
rr <- rasterize( x=p, y=r, update=TRUE, field=500 )

# Then change it to NA
rr[ rr==500 ] <- NA
```

Results are the same as above.